# "Newest" Tab on Search Result Truncates Search Result

Tags: support, search

I've been working for many months on editing "MSSQL" out of question titles and replacing it with "SQL Server". I've been using the search `http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=intitle%3A1+mssql`, which returns four pages of results (down from five, I'm proud to say).

However, when I click the "Newest" tab, I get a page full of results, and then the page displays again with only a few results (four the first time I did it today, now three).

I've never seen such behavior from the search results before.

---

This may be related to the page size calculation. I switched to using the "Active" tab, and noticed that it also did not show a full screen (50) of questions. However, it *did* show the pager at the bottom of the screen, and paging to the "Next" page worked.

Also, switching to 30 questions per page showed an empty screen!

---

The fact that I get a full page when using the "Relevance" tab fooled me into not trying the following simple experiment: turn off "hide ignored tags".

Doing that showed that the entire first page of search results were in hidden tags. I believe it is well-known (or at least, "known") that the paging algorithm first fills up a page, then removes questions in hidden tags, if you have "hide ignored" set. Since the first page has nothing but ignored tags, the entire page was empty.

I didn't even bother to look at the bottom of the page for the pager, since it looked like the page was empty!

I still don't understand why none of the tabs shows more than four pages of results whether or not I'm hiding tags, but that's a different question.

Comment: try in a different web browser to rule out your hidden/ignored tags.

Comment: Jeff, I'm not sure what you mean. Please outline an experiment you'd like me to try, and I'll try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you got any hidden/ignored tags configured? This is the type of behaviour you would see if you viewed a search results page where most of the questions are tagged something in your ignore list (that is, "Hide Ignored Tags" is checked in your prefs).

Comment: I do have ignored tags configured, but keep in mind I get a full list while on the "Relevence" tab.

Comment: This seems to be the problem, along with a bug and a mis(understood)-feature.